# Why are node modules working on firebase emulator but not working post deployment?

Tags: firebase, node-modules, web-deployment, firebase-hosting, intl-tel-input

I am using intl-tel-input in my project which I installed using npm. Every thing seems to work fine when I test using Firebase emulators but it stops working post deployment.

Upon checking the Sources tab in Chrome dev tools, I can see that the module is not properly included. (Pls check images) However, I am completely unable to figure out why. Please help!

[Emulator Screenshot with the Telephone Input field working fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFWjt.png)

[Screenshot taken post deployment with the Telephone input field broken.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Besgi.png)

[Source File - intlTelInput.js located at /node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZVDl.png)

[Source File - intlTelInput.css located at /node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8z46.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Firebase [ignores](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#specify-files-to-deply) `node_modules` directories when deploying.

There are a few options you could use to resolve this.

1. Use a build tool like Rollup or Webpack to generate bundles that include node dependencies.
2. Copy required `node_modules` files to a different directory like `assets` and load them from there.
3. Update `firebase.json` to not ignore `node_modules` on deploy. Note that this will probably greatly increase the size of deployed applications if you have any number of node packages.

Comment: I managed to solve this myself by using suggestion number (3) as given above. To avoid slowing down the application, I had to move unused node packages to a different directory or delete them altogether. To complete the deploy successfully, I had to delete the cache in the .firebase folder. All in all, this approach worked. Thank you for your help.